# Proxy auth required with HTTP post request through proxy

Tags: go

I have proxyString `123.44.333.42:51244`
and want to request url through the proxy

```
proxyString := "123.44.333.42:51244"
proxyURL, err := url.Parse("http://"+proxyStr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ////adding the proxy settings to the Transport object
    transport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
    }
client := &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
        CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
            return http.ErrUseLastResponse
        }}
        resp, contents := getContent(client, person.personHref)
```

get errror `Proxy Authentication Required`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization

Comment: There is no question here but only a statement that your proxy requires authentication. Obviously you don't provide any. And we cannot know what the proper authentication for your specific proxy is. Apart from that an IP address of `123.44.333.42` makes no sense - the `333` is definitely wrong there (should be at most `255`).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think it is safe to assume that we are looking at an obfuscated IP.